# Why is WP ignoring my line breaks?

Tags: line-breaks

WP is using `TinyMCE` as a WYSiWYG editor. So why then is WP ignoring my line breaks?
I really shouldn't have to do: `echo wpautop( $some_long_text );`

[image]

(large picture: http://prntscr.com/4re6xv)

Here is my custom code. I've added `wpautop` in order to get line breaks. But I shouldn't have to, should I?

```
// Get tile / content based on selected language

function getContent(){
    global $lang;
    global $post;

    if($lang == 'no') {
        return get_the_content();
    } else {
        return get_custom_field('content_en',$post->ID);
    }
}

function theContent(){
    $content = getContent();
    echo wpautop($content);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried "the_content()" instead of theContent() ?

Comment: It's my own function due to language. I'll add the code.